# Convert character input to vector of integers [r]

Tags: r, xlsx

How can I convert a character string such as `"c(1:10)"` into an actual vector of integers? My issue is that I need to read a bunch of files using `read.xlsx` from the package xlsx, but I need to read different rows for each file. I've got a separate file that I can read into the workspace as a data.frame (call it "MyFile") that lists in one column the names of the files and, in another column, which rows to read, but I don't know how to convert the character string into the numbers I need. I'd use regex to extract it, but that sounds like more work than I want since it's a mishmash of everything from `"c(1:10)"` to `"c(2, 4, 6:8, 21)"`.

I've tried:

```
 Files <- list()
 for (i in 1:nrow(MyFiles)){
       Files[[i]] <- read.xlsx(MyFiles$File[i], 
                              sheetName = MyFiles$Tab[i],
                              rowIndex = MyFiles$Row[i])
 }
```

but R doesn't know what to do with the row specification since it's currently reading it as a character string.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find that other answer until you pointed me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shame there isn't a better way (as far as I know) than `eval(parse(text=` but that's what I use in these situations.

```
input <- "c(1:10)"
output <- eval(parse(text=input))
output
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```